# Obtener un listado de Productos con una relacion de 4 tablas SQL Server

Tags: sql

estoy tratando de obtener un listado de productos vendidos en el ultimo mes, con cierta caracteristica, que en este caso seria su codigo de clasificacion.
La cuestion es que tengo 4 tablas relacionadas, Productos, ClasificacionProductos, DetalleVentas, EncavesadoVentas.

Ahora bien, esto lo he hecho solo con tres tablas que seria asi:

```
SELECT DISTINCT( p.CodPro) AS 'Code',p.NomPro AS 'Product Name',
CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,0),p.PreVta) AS 'Price'
FROM Productos p INNER JOIN DetVtas d
ON p.CodPro = d.CodPro
WHERE p.CodCla IN (01,02,05)
AND p.Desactivado = 0
ORDER BY p.CodPro ASC;
```

Como veran, esto me arroja un listado de los productos vendidos, que puedo encontrar en detalles de ventas con cierta clasificacion que deseo.

Ahora, quiero hacer lo mismo pero con cierta longitud de fecha, obteniendo un listdo del mes que yo quiera, ya en este caso relacionar la tabla EncVtas (Encabeza Ventas) donde se registra la fecha de la factura con la tabla DetVtas (Detalle Ventas) que es la que registra los detalles de la factura.

Este es el diagrama de ejemplo, no meto todos los campos porque seria muy grande la consulta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien si me puede orientar por favor, por donde va la cosa.

Saludos gente.

Comment: Dentro de las tablas que quieres agregar a la consulta ¿tienen algún campo en común con las tablas que ya están en la consulta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El campo que relaciona la tabla DetVtas con la tabla EncVentas es NumFactura, por tal motivo tu INNER JOIN debes hacerlo relacionando estos dos campos. Por otro lado para seleccionar un mes en específico puedes utilizar las funciones MONTH y YEAR, la consulta quedaría así:

```
SELECT DISTINCT( p.CodPro) AS 'Code',p.NomPro AS 'Product Name',
CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,0),p.PreVta) AS 'Price'  
FROM Productos p 
INNER JOIN DetVtas d ON p.CodPro = d.CodPro
INNER JOIN EncVtas e ON e.NumFactura = d.NumFactura
WHERE 
p.CodCla IN (01,02,05)
AND 
p.Desactivado = 0
AND
(
MONNTH(e.FecFactura) = 1 -- El número del mes siendo entre 1 (Enero) y hasta 12  (Diciembre)
AND
YEAR(e.FecFactura) = 2018 -- El año que deseas filtrar
)
ORDER BY p.CodPro ASC;
```

Comment: Muchas gracas Alfredo, creo que si e sirve su sugerencia, gracias.